# Do Zendframework2 has symfony kind of generator.yml?

Tags: symfony, symfony1, zend-framework2

I am basically from a symfony background, just tried to learn the zend-framework2 a couple of days back. Just finding Not that interesting as symfony, In symfony we can solve many issues in just a single file. "generator.yml" like changing a table list column header or it can be `max_per_page :, filters: [], display: [],`

```
object_actions:
       _edit:         ~
       _delete:       ~
```

And many more...

Have not found any such configuration file, where by a piece of code, can solve the problem instantly. I agree that i may have not reached Up to that level of learning zendframework, if it already has such kind of cofiguration.

In General, please List me the files or any reference link where i can see some interesting tips or tricks on solving the problem, as symfony does with its configaration and .yml files

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks are different and that's the best thing about them all, be it ZF2, Sf2, Laravel or whatever is our there. Each have their pros and their cons. A Tool like you've requested doesn't exist within ZF2. And as far as I can recall a Module for great CRUD functionality has yet to be created, too.